# Python: Parse inconsistent list into list of lists, setting first and last item of each sublist

Tags: python, list

This question has been asked with numerous variants, but I've yet to find one with this set of criteria.

I'm reading lines from a file into a list. I want to create sublists beginning with lines beginning in "0 " and ending with lines beginning with "TR ID".

For example:

```
lines = ['0 01 31DEC', '18:19:08', 'TR ID: 308', '0 02 31DEC', '18:19:08', 'ATC ID: 21232', 'TR ID: 308', '0 03 31DEC', '18:19:08', 'TR ID: 308', '0 04 31DEC', '18:19:08', 'ATC ID: 21232', 'TR ID: 308']
```

The desired result would be:

```
desired_result = [['0 01 31DEC', '18:19:08', 'TR ID: 308'], ['0 02 31DEC', '18:19:08', 'ATC ID: 21232', 'TR ID: 308'], ['0 03 31DEC', '18:19:08', 'TR ID: 308'], ['0 04 31DEC', '18:19:08', 'ATC ID: 21232', 'TR ID: 308']]
```

I have tried getting the indices of each beginning and ending line in order to do some joining, but that seems clunky. Is there a better way of doing this?

UPDATE:

These have all been great directions to go, and I've made some progress, but I should have mentioned that there are some blocks of lines in between each desired sublist that are irrelevant, hence the need to specify a beginning line, not just an ending line. Without specifying the beginning line, some sublists scoop up the irrelevant lines in the beginning of the sublist.

Answer (score 1):

Try iteration:

```
outlist = []; templist = []
for i in lines:
    if i.startswith("TR ID"):   # ending criteria alone seems sufficient for this data
        templist.append(i)
        outlist.append(templist)
        templist = []
    else:
        templist.append(i)

for o in outlist:  # see created list
    print(o)
```

Output:

```
['0 01 31DEC', '18:19:08', 'TR ID: 308']
['0 02 31DEC', '18:19:08', 'ATC ID: 21232', 'TR ID: 308']
['0 03 31DEC', '18:19:08', 'TR ID: 308']
['0 04 31DEC', '18:19:08', 'ATC ID: 21232', 'TR ID: 308']
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice place for a generator:

```
def segment(lines):
    out = []
    for line in lines:
        out.append(line) 
        if line.startswith('TR ID'):
            yield out
            out = []
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lines = ['0 01 31DEC', '18:19:08', 'TR ID: 308', '0 02 31DEC', '18:19:08', 'ATC ID: 21232', 'TR ID: 308', '0 03 31DEC',
         '18:19:08', 'TR ID: 308', '0 04 31DEC', '18:19:08', 'ATC ID: 21232', 'TR ID: 308']

indices = [i for i in range(len(lines)) if lines[i][0] == '0'] + [-1] # [-1] for the last element
result = [lines[indices[i]:indices[i + 1]] for i in range(len(indices) - 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to go with recursion approach:

```
lines = ['0 01 31DEC', '18:19:08', 'TR ID: 308', '0 02 31DEC', '18:19:08', 'ATC ID: 21232', 'TR ID: 308', '0 03 31DEC', '18:19:08', 'TR ID: 308', '0 04 31DEC', '18:19:08', 'ATC ID: 21232', 'TR ID: 308']

final_result=[]
def hello(lines_1):
    data=[]



    if not lines_1:
        return 0
    else:
        for j,i in enumerate(lines_1):
            if i.startswith('TR ID'):
                data.append(i)

                final_result.append(data)



                return hello(lines_1[j+1:])

            else:
                data.append(i)

hello(lines)

print(final_result)
```

output:

```
[['0 01 31DEC', '18:19:08', 'TR ID: 308'], ['0 02 31DEC', '18:19:08', 'ATC ID: 21232', 'TR ID: 308'], ['0 03 31DEC', '18:19:08', 'TR ID: 308'], ['0 04 31DEC', '18:19:08', 'ATC ID: 21232', 'TR ID: 308']]
```